# Почему не работает поиск ASP MVC JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть контроллер, вот такого типа, который возвращает JSON

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadDataFromAD()
        {

            //Get parameters
            var v = ActiveDirectory.GetUserFromAD();
            // get Start (paging start index) and length (page size for paging)
            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
            //Get Sort columns value
            var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

            //find search columns info
            var contactName = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[0][search][value]").FirstOrDefault();


            //SEARCHING...
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactName))
            {
                v = v.Where(a => a.DisplayName.Contains(contactName));
            }


            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int totalRecords = 0;


            totalRecords = v.Count();

            var data = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

В переменную contactName корректно передаются данные.

```
//SEARCHING...
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactName))
            {
                v = v.Where(a => a.DisplayName.Contains(contactName));
            }
```

Ошибка возникает при попытке поиска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, когда я вместо Contains пишу вот так

```
 v = v.Where(a => a.DisplayName==contactName);
```

И ввожу полную строку для поиска в таблице все срабатывает на ура. Помогите!

Comment: Так у вас DisplayName может быть пуст. да и v

Comment: `a.DisplayName != null && aDisplayName.Contains(...`

Comment: Напишите свое решение в ответ.Чтобы я мог закрыть вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строковые переменные могут иметь значение `null`. Добавьте проверку:

```
a.DisplayName != null && aDisplayName.Contains(...
```